# How to style PopupMenu?

Tags: android, user-interface

is it possible to change pop-up menu style from default black text on white background to dark background without applying style to the whole activity (which breaks my UI)?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621070/get-context-of-popupmenu-like-contextmenu

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Yes, you can

```
<style name="YOURSTYLE.PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
</style>
```

And

```
Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.YOURSTYLE_PopupMenu);
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, view);
```

---

**Result**

[image: custom PopupMenu style in Android]

Comment: How can we reduce width of popup menu

Comment: This removes the ripple effect from the menu items, any way to keep it?

Comment: Does not work for Light/Dark Theme.

Answer (score 47):

You cannot set `PopupMenu` style directly, but there are other ways.

`PopupMenu` is created the following way:

```
PopupMenu popupMenu=new PopupMenu(context, anchorView);
```

The style of menu is determined by the style of context you pass. So all you need to do is to pass your `Activity` reference as context, and menu will be styled accordingly.

If you want to define the style yourself, inherit your activity style from one of the default ones and override the following items:

```
<style name="style" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">...</item>
    <item name="android:popupAnimationStyle">...</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">...</item>
    <!-- etc etc -->
</style>
```

Comment: What are the values to set in place of "....".
I tried------------------------

 <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>

------------------------------I am not able to see any change in my popup menu[i did not use other two property]-----------------------

And I am assigning the activity style as this style. Please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Santosh checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320663/change-background-popupmenu-in-android

Answer (score 37):

Adding to what [Deville](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1318939/deville) suggested, you can also add the following attributes to your theme style.

```
<style name="style" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">        
    <!-- other attributes -->
    <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge</item>

    <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall</item>

    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/myPopupMenuStyle</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/myPopupMenuStyle</item>
</style>
```

Other styles referenced in the above style definition

```
<style name="myPopupMenuStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">

</style>
<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

You would notice **AppCompat** in my xml style definitions, that is because I am using the android support library to target lower android API Levels.

Comment: Do you know how can I change the background colour of the popup menu also using the support library? thx

Comment: This removes the border around the popup.

Comment: this works, but I changed my minimum sdk from 10 to 11

Answer (score 6):

use the same context of the `ActionBar` to create the `PopupMenu`

***actionBar.getThemedContext()***

So,

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
PopupMenu popMenu = new PopupMenu(actionBar.getThemedContext(), someView);
```

Comment: You're assuming the use of Actionbar. Popup can be used without the Actionbar.

Comment: This works well even with the toolbar if it is set as support Actionbar. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I am styling popup menu a little bit differently than others.

So, I've created a style

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textContrast</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/text</item>
</style>
```

And I'm using toolbar

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And set popup style like this

```
toolbar.setPopupTheme(R.style.AppTheme_PopupMenu);
```

Comment: I found so many 'solutions' each more convoluted then the other. But this one is straight to the point and most useful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

After maybe a hundred posts here, I find Kirill Smirnov answered the post back in 2019! That answer is in Java.

I'm in Kotlin v.1.7.0 in Android Studio version Chipmunk and called the style like this in the main activity and in the onCreate method:

```
binding.toolbar.popupTheme = R.style.AppTheme_PopupMenu
```

Note that the:

```
ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light
```

works as the parent too.

But all this time I was really after the background as it adds consistency to the toolbar and its menu in an Android app. I added this background line that runs in day and night themes on my Android v.11 phone:

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/blue_dark</item>
</style>
```