# How to set the background of Android PopupMenu to White

Tags: java, android, popupmenu

I'm struggling with setting the background of PopupMenu. After googling it for a while, I found it should goes to the app theme. To be more specific, this should be defined in the style.xml.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">MY_STYLE</item>
</style>
```

However, I didn't really figure out which style exactly I should use, as I assume there's a built-in one. I tried with `@android:style/Widget.Holo.PopupMenu` and `@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu`, but with no luck.

Comment: See answer on this [qustion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636101/how-to-style-popupmenu)

Comment: I've seen it actually; I tried with setting `popupMenuStyle` to `Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu` as well as `popupBackground` to `@android:color/background_light`, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For instance, try something like this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.MyAppTheme</item>
</style>
```

And then on the style itself:

```
<style name="PopupMenu.MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/popup_menu_bg_color</item>
</style>
```

That is the way it's done via [ActionBarStyleGenerator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) and some old references here on the [Developer Site](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But where is the @drawable/pop_menu_bg_color? I didn't find it in the res generated by ActionBarStyleGenerator.

Comment: It should rather be: 
parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow"