# Dark actionbar with white dropdown menu from Holo Light

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I've got an custom theme with a parent @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar
I want to change the dropdown menu into the white version (see image)

I have looked up some examples, but they didn't work out for me, is it possible to just override the dropdown menu from the DarkActionBar with the light version?

(I dont use the sherlock actionbar)

[image]

Comment: I tend to just use this http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: Check out this post, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878662/how-to-set-the-background-of-android-popupmenu-to-white](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878662/how-to-set-the-background-of-android-popupmenu-to-white) I think it is the same issue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This worked for me. Hope it help:

```
<style name="YOUR_DARK_AB_THEME">
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/YourActionBarWidget</item>
</style>

<!-- This helps the PopupMenu stick with Light theme while the ActionBar is in Dark theme -->
<style name="YourActionBarWidget"
    parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Any chance this just doesn't work in Light.DarkActionbar? I keep getting the dark dropdown. - Doesn't seem to work with default dark either. maybe because I'm using AppCompat

Comment: As expected, same thing for Material themes (replace `Holo` with `Material`, of course).

Answer (score 1):

use the same context of actionBar to create the PopupMenu

***actionBar.getThemedContext()***

So,

> ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)
>   getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
>   PopupMenu popMenu = new PopupMenu(actionBar.getThemedContext(), anyView);