# Cannot style style popupmenu background color with Material theme

Tags: android, material-design

I'm using the **@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar** as base for my theme in my values-21
folder.

Now I would like to change so that spinners in the actionbar as well as the dropdownmenu for the overflow button gets the style from the Light material theme, black text on white background.

But I can not get it to work, I have searched like crazy, tried all the methods I can find but they don't seem to work in the L preview. I also looked at the google i/o -14 app, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what's what.

Comment: have you tried `http://stackoverflow.com/a/22215033/1922137`?

Comment: thank you very much! i was using `popupMenuStyle` in the root of my theme. now it is working.

Comment: Thanks, this did works great! I would really like to give you credit, but I can't since you only commented?