# How to set the background for popup menu?

Tags: android

I want to set the background of my popup menu like in the given image:

[image]

Is there any way to set this background for the given popup menu in android? If anyone have any idea please help me in accomplishing this.

Comment: That is `alpha`. Use alpha property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the background of Android PopupMenu to White](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878662/how-to-set-the-background-of-android-popupmenu-to-white)

Comment: I have already used this sir but its not working for me.

Comment: bhai is image me popup menu hai konsa..?

Comment: Gopal bro in which logout, delete edit button are showing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can style your pop-up menu in the `xml` file

Like this:

I simply change the color to #ffffff means Hex white!

```
    <style name="style" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">...</item>
    <item name="android:popupAnimationStyle">...</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#ffff</item>
    <!-- etc etc -->
```

Comment: Amin bro  I am using the same code putting my popup background color same as i required but still it is giving the same .

Comment: Did you define PopupMenu Class?

Comment: Where i have to define my PopupMenu class. What i have done i have made a popup menu xml file and put it in menu folder, and code for generating a popup menu in my Activity class and if i am putting background color in style.xml file for popupmenu its not working.