# How to keep Popup menu background white

Tags: android, android-toolbar, popupmenu

If I use **sample A** the background of the overflow menu is white, just as expected. But if I use **sample B** then the background is black. I need sample B because I want the icons to show. But I need to keep the background white. How do I do that?

**Sample A**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_dogs, menu);
}
```

**Sample B**

```
findViewById(R.id.moreMenuBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), v);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_dogs);
                forceShowIcon(popupMenu);
                popupMenu.show();
}
public static void forceShowIcon(PopupMenu popup) {
        try {
            Field[] fields = popup.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : fields) {
                if ("mPopup".equals(field.getName())) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Object menuPopupHelper = field.get(popup);
                    Class<?> classPopupHelper = Class.forName(menuPopupHelper
                            .getClass().getName());
                    Method setForceIcons = classPopupHelper.getMethod(
                            "setForceShowIcon", boolean.class);
                    setForceIcons.invoke(menuPopupHelper, true);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

app theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: which theme are you using in the activity

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878662/how-to-set-the-background-of-android-popupmenu-to-white

Comment: I don't think the these is the problem since it works fine when I go the normal route: but I will edit to show my theme

Comment: @RageshRamesh I cannot resolve `@style/Theme.Holo.Light` or `@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow`

Comment: @RageshRamesh it helps me get there. Thanks.

Comment: change that to @style/Theme.Holo.Light  to Theme.AppCompat.Light and  @style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow to Base.Widget.AppCompat.ListPopupWindow

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add popupMenu style to ur **AppTheme**:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

**manifest.xml:**

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
.............
</application>
```