# PopupMenu - Customize Text (Size/Color) in Menu Resource Items

Tags: android, android-menu

I have created a PopupMenu that is inflated OnClick of a LinearLayout. I want the Menu Items to have a specific `textColor` and `textSize`; however, Menu Items seem to have a very restricted set of XML attributes and I can't find a way to reference a style. Any ideas?

**PopupMenu:**

```
customerMenu = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.customerMenu);
customerMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), customerMenu);
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.addcustomermenu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.show();
       }
});
```

**Menu Resource:**

*res/menu/addcustomermenu.xml*

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/customerButtonOne"
        android:title="Create New Customer" >
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/customerButtonTwo"
        android:title="Search Existing Customer">
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636101/how-to-style-popupmenu

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know.. the text of menu item will not be changed..

so.. most of the APP use the basic text of menu item..

this is only I think..