# PopupMenu - custom theme

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I'd like to create a custom PopupMenu (be able to change text color, background and icon). Ideal behavior would be like on this gfy (taken from Solid Explorer):

https://gfycat.com/JealousMeanHorsefly

[image]

Do you think it's a PopupMenu or ListPopupWindow? I was trying to style PopupMenu like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170962/popupmenu-customize-text-size-color-in-menu-resource-items), but I've only managed to change background color (oh and shadow disappeared). **Any ideas how to create such a beautiful dialog?**

Comment: I would use a ListPopupWindow for that

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to implement it by creating a custom dialog then set its content view.

```
          Dialog d = new Dialog(hostActivity,R.style.customOne);
          d.setContentView(yourPopupView);
          d.show();
```

and u need to change the style of the dialog as below

```
     <style name="customOne" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
    </style>
```

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this library: https://github.com/shehabic/Droppy

It allows you to create custom popups/drop-down menus.

Answer (score 0):

```
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
<item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/popupText</item>
<item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/popupTextSmall</item>
```

Add the above fields in your base theme.You can further customise your text in the below styles.

```
<style name="popupText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
</style>

<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/popupbackgroundColor</item>
</style>
<style name="popupTextSmall" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
</style>
```

Also refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20318161/4321808) to show images in popup

You can also set PopupTheme in toolbar.

Comment: There're couple of problems: 1) When I set ```<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>``` background color isn't changing. 2) ```When I set <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>``` background color does chaging, but the popup shadow disappeares.