# How to change background color popup menu android

Tags: android, menu, colors, popup

I generate each option of menu from querying database.
Here is my code.

```
final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getBaseContext(), v); 
SQLiteDatabase db = AdapterDb.getReadableDatabase(); 
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
int ctritem = 0;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, ctritem, Menu.NONE, "ALL ITEMS"); 
    do {
        ctritem++;   
        popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, ctritem, Menu.NONE, cursor.getString(0)); 
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Everything is okay, but the problem is how to change color of option menu or background color of popup menu (from black to white), Is it possible ?
Thanks

Comment: could you help me Peter?Thanks

Comment: Oops! Google Chrome could not find pastebin.com

Comment: i can see my posting source code @ pastebin, aren't you?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Add popupMenu style to ur AppTheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

manifest.xml:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
.............
</application>
```

Comment: and then how I call it in the programm?

Comment: Automatically it will apply to your popup menu.

Comment: still same, i put it on folder res/values, but it doesn't work

Comment: Did u apply this apptheme to application in ur manifest.xml. See my edit

Comment: @user3172337 : now is working, i had mistake on android manifest. Thanks

Comment: This is working for me. Can I change Text color of Popupmenu ?

Comment: Have you controlled the context you passed to the constructor?
I had the same problem when using:
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, v);
I was passing the wrong context to the PopupMenu constructor.

Comment: what about the shadow?? with the following it losses the shadow

Comment: how to do it if i am using AppTheme.NoActionBar. i mean it is not working in use i use noactionbar .

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320663/change-background-popupmenu-in-android

Comment: @silverFoxA Shadow can set using setElevation in style. `<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:popupElevation">3dp</item>
    </style>`

Comment: I think this answer is not complete and one can not solve the issue just by reading this incomplete post

Comment: If your `AppTheme` is based on `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar`, you inherit `@style/Widget.Material3.PopupMenu` to keep the shadow, like so: `<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.Material3.PopupMenu">`

Comment: It works for a regular Android, however if your device is Nvidia Shield, then no luck. Although text color can be changed using: android:itemTextAppearance, so it should be a similar trick for background.

Comment: Great. works well for popup menu :)

Answer (score 23):

Please Add Following lines in style xml file, I hope this will help for material design application.
**Style.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

    <!-- To change the popup menu and app text color  -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>

    <!-- To change the background of options menu-->
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/skyBlue</item>
</style>
```

For more details refer this link http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/01/how-to-change-background-and-text-color-of-android-actionbar-option-menu.html

Comment: Worked for me! Feb 2020.

Comment: Better use `android:itemTextAppearance` instead of `android:textColor`. Tested. Works.

Comment: Also `android:itemBackground` better be drawable where you define behaviour for default state and pressed state. If you set `android:itemBackground` as a color the items loose ripple effect

Answer (score 13):

If your are using AppCompact-v7 then you can style PopupMenu as below:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenuStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="popupMenuStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

NOTE: PopMenu always works with Activity Context, not with Application context.

Comment: It works if you create the PopupMenu with the Activity Context like this: new PopupMenu(getActivity(), ...) e not like this: new PopupMenu(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ...).

Comment: PopMenu always works with Activity Context, not with Application context. If you Down vote this post then I am requesting you that please up vote it.

Comment: You last voted on this answer Nov 14 at 16:20. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited. Not able right now...

Comment: Using getActivity() rather than application context fixed it for me!

Comment: @Dunfield Great, You can upvote it for help others to identify this as workable solution.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using AppCompat theme then use

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/black</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>
```

otherwise

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>

</style>
```

Comment: The AppCompat version didn't work for me. The menu background is still white.

Answer (score 3):

at first define your style for popup menu background in styles.xml file
in my case i use this...

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>
</style>
```

here i want to change popup menu background in a specific activity , so apply theme(android:theme="@style/AppTheme") with activity declaration and it's surely working.
 another important thing to create popup menu using this code PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(your activity, viewObj);

Answer (score 3):

Add PopupMenu theme to your AppTheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/PopupMenuTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenuTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

manifest.xml:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the layout where you are giving toolbar, specify theme by         app:popupTheme="@style/MyPopupMenu"

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#2196F3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    style="@style/DrawerArrowStyle"
    app:popupTheme="@style/MyPopupMenu">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought this fixed it but I really just had to change to getActivity() as the context when creating the popup.

Answer (score 2):

**In  Style**
**Your Application Theme**

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
     <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
 <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/list_background</item>
 <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item>
    </style>
```

**For Text Appearence**

```
 <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@color/list_item_title</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyActionBarTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/list_item_title</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle"
        parent="style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/list_item_title</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
```

**And Use App Theme In Menifest like:**

```
<application
        android:name="Your Package"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Answer (score 2):

> ### There is no need to do changes in ANDROIDMAINFEST.xml

> ### checkout this
>
> you can achieve it by this in fragment or in activity by provideing or masking with it custom theme and after making the custom theme you have to pass that context to the popup menu.
> first  create popup menu layout in menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/remove"
        android:title="Remove downloads"

        />
</menu>
```

> second style it in style.xml

```
 <style name="CustomPopUpStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/bgColor</item>
</style>
```

> method

```
 private fun showPopupMenu(context: Context, view: View) {
        var wrapper: Context =  ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.CustomPopUpStyle)
        val popup = PopupMenu(wrapper, view)
        popup.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu)
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener { item: MenuItem? ->
            when (item!!.itemId) {
                R.id.remove -> {
                    Toast.makeText(context, item.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

            true
        })

        popup.show()
    }
```

> lastly initialization

```
 showPopupMenu(holder.itemView.context, holder.viewDataBinding.more)
```

> and this i did in adapter of recyclerview which is in fragment

> ### hope you liked it.
>
> ### the code is self explanatory too.

Answer (score 1):

Please Refer [How to style PopupMenu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636101/how-to-style-popupmenu?answertab=active#tab-top) for more explanation. I was facing the same issue, searched alot but found the solution in the link mentioned.

PopupMenu is created in following way :

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view);
```

PopupMenu takes the styling of the context which is passed, Passing Activity as the context solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="AppTheme1" parent= "android:Theme.DeviceDefault">

    <item name="android:actionBarPopupTheme">@style/popupNew</item>
</style>

<style name="popupNew" parent="android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Please explain why your proposal solves the OP's problem.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your style.xml file

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Set the style on Spinner

```
<Spinner
android:theme="@style/PopupMenu"
android:popupMenuStyle="@style/PopupMenu"/>
```

This would work for API level 16+ devices too.

Answer (score -2):

You can use custom layout like this..

```
PopupMenu pop = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, v);
pop.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, pop.getMenu());
pop.show();
```

Design layout how you want..hope this helps..

Comment: means? tried? I dnt knw your requirment...if you use popup dialog then you can change bg color

Comment: @vnshetty I'm using it but I cannot change the textSize of the items. I have tried lots of examples by changing text size in styles.xml but nothing worth.