# Cannot change the popupmenu color

Tags: android, popupmenu

I am trying to change the color of a pop-up menu. 
 This is the code I am defining in the styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopUp</item>
</style>

<style name="PopUp" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/test_color</item>
</style>
```

p.s. my actionBar color is changed in java file, NOT is styles.xml
Thank you!

Comment: Are you inflating a layout for the popup?

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231404/how-to-change-background-color-popup-menu-android