# How to change background color option menu xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, popupmenu

i try change background color option menu from black to white
but my code not work.i see this link too [How to change background color popup menu android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231404/how-to-change-background-color-popup-menu-android) but its not work for me.

styles

```
  <style name="Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Base.Theme.DesignDemo">
  </style>

  <style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
      <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
     </style>
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>

</style>

</resources>
```

popup_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <!--///showAsAction="always" ///-->
  <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="Share" showAsAction="always" />
  <item android:id="@+id/action_settings1" android:title="Bluetooth" showAsAction="always" />
  <item android:id="@+id/action_settings2" android:title="Exit" showAsAction="always" />
  <!--/android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/-->
  <item android:id="@+id/action_settings3" android:title="Share" android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
  <item android:id="@+id/action_settings4" android:title="Bluetooth" android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to change background color option menu

Have you controlled the context you passed to the constructor? When you create a `PopupMenu` class, please use the `Activity` context like this :

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, anchorView);//Not BaseContext
```

Whether you use [android.widget.PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html) or [android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html)? They governed by different theme attributes :

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <!-- if using android.widget.PopupMenu -->
     <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
     <!-- if using android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu -->
     <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
 </style/>

 <style name="PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
     <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
 </style>
```

Effect like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH5oI.gif).