# How to Change Background of Popup for a Spinner in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, spinner, android-spinner

I want to change the background of pop-up for a spinner, basically, I want to put the image for pop-up as I did for my app background. I read many suggestions and made the proper entries for android:popupBackground, but it's still not working.

I have been really looking for a solution for a month but can't find it. Any help is very much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<Spinner
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="@dimen/input_field_height"
   android:prompt="@string/state_select_text"
   android:id="@+id/home_adr_state"
   android:textColor="@color/input_color_text"
   android:spinnerMode="dialog"
   android:entries="@array/State_list"
   android:popupBackground="@drawable/app_bg" 
/>
```

Comment: done post a picture of your code.... copy and paste the code

Comment: to answer your question... you use a hex value.. not a drawable.

Comment: <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/input_field_height"
                android:prompt="@string/state_select_text"
                android:id="@+id/home_adr_state"
                android:textColor="@color/input_color_text"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                android:entries="@array/State_list"
                android:popupBackground="@drawable/app_bg" />

Comment: Tried Hex value , but still not working :(

Comment: <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/input_field_height"
                android:prompt="@string/state_select_text"
                android:id="@+id/home_adr_state"
                android:textColor="@color/input_color_text"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                android:entries="@array/State_list"
                android:popupBackground="#7f7f7f" />

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231404/how-to-change-background-color-popup-menu-android

Comment: Did that but still not working :(,

Comment: styles xml -

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    </style> 

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">