# How to change background of popup menu dialog programmatically

Tags: android, styles

Am showing a pop up menu dialog programmatically when a button is clicked.

```
 ImageButton Btn = findViewById(R.id.Btn);
        Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(), v);
                menu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "A");
                menu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "B");
                menu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 3, 3, "C. You were sent to heal...");
                menu.show();
            }
        });
```

Now, I want to style the pop up menu dialog and change the background color. 
This is what I used in my **styles.xml**

```
<item name="android:itemBackground">@color/darkBlue</item>
```

However, I don't get any changes in my output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change background color popup menu android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231404/how-to-change-background-color-popup-menu-android)

Comment: am setting pop up menu programmatically as you can see from one code

Comment: Ya it's Widget so you can use Widget.PopupMenu in style to change it's background.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the color in your apps theme. at the .xml -file

```
    <style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/darkBlue</item>
    </style>
```