# Is there a way to do In app updates for iOS apps like on Android

Tags: ios, in-app-update, app-update

I saw a great way of handling app updates by Android, here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates). Android has exposed a way to check from app if a new update is available and inform user, app can download update which can be installed later. We can also for user to update app for critical updates.

Has apple done anything recently for handling app updates? I am looking for similar kind of implementation for iOS apps.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/21231556/2219208

Comment: With iOS, you cannot update code without submitting a new version to the AppStore. You can, however, update data from your server (very common), and even write your code to change the UI based on your updated data. You can also query the AppStore to check for an updated version and then prompt the user to install it --- but the install must be done through the AppStore.

Comment: @DonMag, thanks for the reply. I know the things that you have mentioned but wanted to know if something similar to Android is available on iOS. Just go through that, it's a good way to solve the problem of customer not updating apps in an elegant way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does iOS has In App updates like feature as of Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043944/does-ios-has-in-app-updates-like-feature-as-of-android)