# how to change option menu background color

Tags: android

I am trying to change option menu background , but there is white space top and bottom
my toolbar style

```
 app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTheme"
   <style name="ThemeOverlay.MyTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

        <!-- To change the popup menu and app text color  -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>

        <!-- To change the background of options menu-->
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/black</item>
    </style>
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the background color of the options menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944244/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-options-menu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There problem with the material theme

```
 <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/bluish_green</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.MyTheme" parent="Theme.MyApplication">
        <!-- To change the popup menu and app text color  -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <!-- To change the background of options menu-->
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>

    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21231556/11629088)?

Create style for menu in your app style and add that entry in theme of your app
don't forgot to add that theme in you menifest's Application tag

**android:theme="@style/AppTheme"**