# android popup menu text color (AppCompat)

Tags: android, colors, popupmenu

I need to change text color of a popuo menu but I don't find any way for do this, I can change background of popmenu but not the text, I edit the style.xml in this way:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->

    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall</item>
</style>

<style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#0F213F</item>
</style>

<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Base.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>

<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Base.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

where is the mistake?

Comment: Define your styles in AppTheme, instead of AppBaseTheme. AppBaseTheme has own implementations for API levels 11 and 14 by default, which redefined your styles.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style PopupMenu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636101/how-to-style-popupmenu)

Comment: @ArtjomB. Some overlap but not a duplicate because this question is specifically about AppCompat popups.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
<item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large</item>
<item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small</item>
```

I think that you are using TextAppearance.AppCompat.Base.Widget.PopupMenu. Here is the error, you are using another parent that doesn´t response the current style.

You have to use:

TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.

Comment: what does this mean? can you edit this so that whatever the OP has done is merged to whatever you intend to be done to resolve the issue?

Comment: I cant change font color. Can you update to full answer all require style.

Comment: This is what I did based on this answer and it worked for me, thanks Alfaplus!                                                                                                 <style name="OverflowMenuText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorToolbarText</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 53):

In styles.xml

```
<style name="itemTextStyle.AppTheme" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
        <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/color_item_popup</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_content</item>
    </style>
```

and add in AppTheme

```
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/itemTextStyle.AppTheme</item>
```

color_item_popup.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/primary_text"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/primary_text"/>
    <item android:color="@color/secondary_text"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 20):

In styles.xml:

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

In java:

`Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.PopupMenu);
 final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(wrapper, view);`

Answer (score 3):

```
//In Main Style
<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenuStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge</item>


  //In Define part

   <style name="popupMenuStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/popup_bg</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>

<style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>

  //you may use this background 
 //popup_bg.xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="135"
    android:centerColor="#c8232323"
    android:endColor="#c80d0d0d"
    android:startColor="#c8434242"
    android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```