# Android Context menu items text is not showing up

Tags: java, android

I have recently come across a problem that the context menu items are not showing up
for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TVc8.png

Current code (Activity)

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if (v.getId() == R.id.txtTotalOwe)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_edit_contact, menu);
    }
}
```

And here is the R.menu.menu_edit_contact

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/edit_contact"
      android:title="Edit Contact"
      android:showAsAction="never"
      android:icon="@null"/>

<item android:id="@+id/edit_delete"
      android:title="Delete Contact"
      android:showAsAction="never"
      android:icon="@null"/>
```

Basically the 2 context menues are displaying, the only problem is the text isn't displaying as it's suppose to.

Comment: override this method...@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.menu_edit_contact, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

Comment: @ExceptionLover I've already tried that method, nothing seemed to work.

Comment: What theme are you using? Check / post your styles.xml

Comment: @jaibatrik https://github.com/wolfbytestudio/Tappers/blob/master/Tappers/app/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml

Comment: See if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652964/android-popup-menu-text-color-appcompat

Comment: @jaibatrik still nothing works, tried more theme changes also