# How do I change color of RadioButtons in PopupMenu?

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

How do I set the color of `RadioButton`s in a checkable `PopupMenu`. I am using the AppCompat version. I successfully set the background color and the text color via the styles, but I cannot figure out how to set the color of the radio buttons.

This is what I have so far;

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/myPopupMenuStyle</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall</item>
    </style>

   <style name="myPopupMenuStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>


   <style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

I have tried many other attributes, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Galdino's reply at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34702166/2661303, and based on Pztar's reply, and with some trial and error, I have figured out the solution. I am using the AppCompat PopupMenu.
Add just the following to your style file (no need to add anything to your main theme);

```
<style name="MyPopupTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Then when creating PopupMenu, use following;

```
Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.MyPopupTheme);
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, bAnchor, Gravity.END | Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP, 0, R.style.MyPopupTheme);
```

I don't know why, but even when using the ContextThemeWrapper, I still have to pass the style to the constructor. As we are using the ContextWrapper, we are using a specific theme for this PopupMenu, therefore we can override the accent color for only the PopupMenu.
So now I have a reversed PopupMenu, with the accent color as the background, the text and buttons in white, and the selected button in the primary color.

Hope this helps somebody,
Lionscribe

Comment: You saved me a day. Thank you!
Don't understand why the style cannot be applied from activity theme: 
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupTheme</item>
It doesn't work (

Answer (score 2):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/radio_button_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/radio_button_color2</item>
</style>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26850668/1269953

`colorAccent` is the primary color for your radio buttons, and `textColorSecondary` is as it says the secondary for when the radio button is not selected. When using `colorAccent` in `AppCompat` note that there is no `android:` prefix this is the correct way of using it on versions below `Lollipop`

Comment: Technically this is right, but you can only do it by changing the theme for the whole activity or app, which is not what I need. I want to specifically change all the colors only in the PopupMenu.

Comment: I have referenced your reply in the accepted solution. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

An easy way [Android Holo Color](http://android-holo-colors.com/)
Choose theme color , ON radio button option , Download zip file copy pics to drwable and copy XML files to in drawable and set them as

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576507/is-it-possible-to-change-the-radio-button-icon-in-an-android-radio-button-group)