# Custom PopupMenu styles are being ignored

Tags: android, android-styles, popupmenu, android-popupwindow

I've been struggling with PopupMenu styling, and after a lot of research, the process of creating a custom PopupMenu style for my theme seemed to be fairly straightfoward. For example the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636101/how-to-style-popupmenu) seems like an easy way to change the background color of a PopupMenu. However, none of these solutions have worked for my project. So I started digging into the style sources to find out what I should actually be inheriting to style the PopupMenu in my own project.

I'm running my tests on a handset running API 19, and my base theme looks like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- ... -->
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/CustomPopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomPopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/retina_burning_hot_pink</item>
</style>
```

This is the solution that most of the accepted answers here show. But this does not style my PopupMenu. So I dug into the sources to find the geneology of my theme and see what default settings where being used. This is what I found:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light"> 
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

And then in `Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light` I found these default settings:

```
<!-- Popup Menu styles -->
<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu</item>
<item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large</item>
<item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small</item>
<item name="listPopupWindowStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListPopupWindow</item>
<item name="dropDownListViewStyle">?android:attr/dropDownListViewStyle</item>
```

So as far as I can tell, my theme inherits from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` which uses a default PopupMenu style of `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu`. I then inherit that style to set my own PopupMenu settings. I made sure my Activity and my Application are all using the correct Theme. I'm not sure why else this just won't work. I've also tried these settings:

```
<item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/CustomPopupMenuLarge</item>
<item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/CustomPopupMenuSmall</item>
<item name="android:popupWindowStyle">@style/CustomPopupMenuListWindow</item>
```

I provided custom styles for each one, and none of them worked. What could be overriding all my custom styles? Any help would be appreciated, because I'm stumped.

---

**EDITS**

Here's my manifest...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.blah.blah">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is `AppTheme.NoActionBar`

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: are you setting the theme in the manifest?

Comment: @Sree - Yes, as stated in the question.

Comment: Can we see the code (you are probably doing it right but just to make sure)

Comment: Where is AppCompat.NoActionbar

Comment: I added it above. I've tried putting the settings in there as well, and it made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Do not specify `android:` in

`<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/CustomPopupMenu</item>`.

Instend:

`<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/CustomPopupMenu</item>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define a parent for `AppCompat.NoActionBar`. Try `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` and also add in `<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/CustomPopupMenu</item>` to it.

Comment: I've already tried this and it made no difference. I tried making `AppTheme` the parent, and now I just gave your suggestion a try and it changes some colors of things, but the PopupMenu remains unchanged.

Comment: Hmm.. that should be working. Can i see the changes you made with my suggestions

Comment: I just changed it the way you suggested. I made the top line `<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` and added `<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/CustomPopupMenu</item>` to the body.

Comment: Do one more thing, make your `CustomPopupMenu`'s parent `parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu"`

Comment: I've already tried that as well, lol. Just tried it again as a sanity check, and nothing changed. I might need to call a priest soon.

Comment: Can you try to make the theme AppTheme and see if that works. That way we know if the problem lies with that theme