# Change color text and background color title of Popup Menu

Tags: java, android, colors, menu, popup

How can i change color text and background color title of Popup Menu?

When i want change another item in popup menu i use something like this :

```
 <style name="itemTextStyle.customTheme" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/green</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10dp</item>
</style>
```

I would like to change only this tittle : 
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMkkd.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style PopupMenu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636101/how-to-style-popupmenu)

Comment: I tried this solution and doesn't work

Comment: what is your app style. or do you have any style for the container activity. let me know.

Comment: <style name="customTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/size_12dip</item>
        <item name="android:contextPopupMenuStyle">@style/myContextPopupMenuStyle</item>
    </style>

I know how change header tittle color from java code, but i use context menu in many activity so i duplicate code...

Answer (score 0):

By getting the object of title, you can customize it

```
TextView alertTitle = (TextView) dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(alertTitleId);
alertTitle.setTextColor(color);
```

Answer (score 0):

ADD POPUPMENU TO Apptheme:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    </style>
    <style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

manifest.xml:

```
     <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    .............
    </application>
```