# Xamarin Forms action bar overflow popup colors

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Visual Studio and Xamarin Forms
I have a Content Page with an action bar and a toolbar button that appears in the overflow popup menu with the following code.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Sample 01" Order="Secondary" Priority="0" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

I would like to change the color of the background of the popup as well as the color of the text of the toolbar items.

Currently and because I have set in the `styles.xml` of the Android solution, the `TextColor` to be black, both the background color and the items appear in black.

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
```

Setting the background to white with the following will not fix the issue because this will alter the appearance of other parts of the app.

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
```

My question is how to set the background color of the popup menu of the action bar specifically without affecting other elements of the app?

Comment: You set these values for `android:popupMenuStyle`?

Comment: This seems to be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636101/how-to-style-popupmenu

Comment: The suggestions in the post that you mentioned, didn’t work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to change the background color of the overflow popup is by inserting the following line in the `style.xml` (Android project)

```
<item name="android:itemBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
```

I found the answer in the following link https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/99515/how-to-make-a-toolbar-like-whats-app-toolbar

Comment: What about the `textColor` ? I tried it and it has changed my entire applications code color. Whereas I want it to just be the overflow menu. Thanks!